# Count occurrences of values based on value in different columns

Tags: r, sum

I have table like this. Column names V1, V2, V3, V4

```
V1 | V2 | V3 | V4
2  |  4 | 3  |  1
2  |  1 | 3  |  1
2  |  3 | NA |  NA
2  |  4 | 3  |  1
3  | NA | NA | NA
```

How can I count the number of occurrences of the number "3" except if number "1" Comes after it in the same row I don't want it to be counted.

in the above example the occurrence of the Value "3" is 2 times

EDIT:

this is a sample of my data, 31 columns... what I'm trying to do is, I want to count how many times a specific value has occurred except if another specific value came in the very next column.

example from the picture, I would like to count the number of occurrence of value 112, how many times did it occur? except it it from the counting if "116" comes in the next column.

please comment me if more clarification needed.

[image]

Comment: When you mean after, do you mean in the column to its right or in the row below?

Comment: @DeveaP I mean to its right column, I will update my post

Comment: What if a 3 appears on the last column and a 1 in the first column the row below? To clarify: element (1,4) is 3 and element (2,1) is 1. Has that 3 to be counted?

Comment: @rawr sorry, its a table

Comment: @nicola 1 can't come before 3 according to the data I have, sorry I will update my post for this point

Comment: Will you count as valid if there is a "1" in the same row of a "3", _not_ consecutively but after a few columns of the one with the 3?

Comment: @alexis_laz no it won't be valid, can you please suggest a way to do it?

Comment: Are there any other constraints like "there is only _one_ 3 or 1 in each row" etc?

Comment: @alexis_laz No there are no contraints, 3 & 1 can only appear once in each row, if 1 appeared in a row, it can appear twice.

Comment: If 3 appears only once in each row, then you could test if the last 1 in that row is after the 3. I.e. after converting your `NA`s to 0, you could use something like `max.col(data == 3L, "first") > max.col(data == 1L, "last") * (rowSums(data == 1L) > 0L)`; this gives `TRUE` in each row where there is no 1 after your only 3.

Comment: @alexis_laz I'd like to get the result in total number not as True/False, because my data is so big

Comment: @RayanSp : Wrap the logical vector with `sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code, I assume that "after" means the column to its right.

What you want, is the sum of events: "3 in column x & column x+1 is different from 1".

Which you can translate into the following code (may not be efficient though):

```
TOTAL<-0    
for( i in 1:(ncol(df)-1){
   TOTAL<-TOTAL + sum(df[,i]==3 & df[,i+1]!=1, na.rm= TRUE)
}
```

**Edit : taking into account last column**

```
TOTAL<-TOTAL+sum(df[,ncol(df)]==3 , na.rm = TRUE)
```

So the full code, is:

```
TOTAL<-0    
for( i in 1:(ncol(df)-1){
   TOTAL<-TOTAL + sum(df[,i]==3 & df[,i+1]!=1,na.rm = TRUE)
}
TOTAL<-TOTAL+sum(df[,ncol(df)]==3, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: @RHertel I'll edit my answer to account for that, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Btw deva, your code works fine, just took me time to try & try

Answer (score 3):

I'd try:

```
sum(tb[,1:3]==3 & (tb[,2:4]!=1 | is.na(tb[,2:4])),na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 2
```

The data I used:

```
tb <- structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 
3L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")))
```